# Encode video with H.265 HEVC in Android

Tags: android, video-encoding, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, h.265

Because of android's lack of support for H.265 HEVC, what would be the best option for allowing the MediaRecorder to encode H.265 HEVC?

Can this be done without using the deprecated Camera class? I intend to use the camera2 API exclusively, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html

There is now a greyed out VideoEncoder option for HEVC(H.265).

If you change the API level in the navigation bar on the left side of the screen to API 24, HEVC becomes revealed.

I think this means we can expect HEVC support once API 24 is available.

Cheers